# NotFoundHttpException Lumen in production

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, lumen

When access Api, return print below:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception
NotFoundHttpException
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWUde.png)

the project is in "back" folder and the url is api/

Root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^api(/(.*))?$ back/public/$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.php [NC,L]
```

.htaccess in public


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: are you in cpanel ?

Comment: Can you paste the url or try your BASE URL/public

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I think you need to add a request capture inside the service container of the app.

For that, You need to add this code inside your `public/index.php`

```
$request = IlluminateHttpRequest::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

Or you can do one other solution by putting this code inside same file

```
$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

Comment: Thanks!
I put the first option, but now is:
Class "IlluminateHttpRequest" not found

I try Illuminate\Http\Request::capture(), but I have the same error NotFoundHttpException